# Build a list tree with an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, arraylist, tree

I want to generate a tree with html elements "ul" and "li". I want the final result to look something like this.

```
My List
    Menu 1
        Menu 2
            Menu 3
        Menu 4
    Menu 5
```

But when I run my code the result looks something like this:

```
My List
    Menu 1
```

Here is my PHP array code:

```
$lists = array(array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Menu 1',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'Menu 2',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 2,
        'name' => 'Menu 3',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'Menu 4',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Menu 5',
    )
));
?>
<ul>
<li><a>My List</a>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($lists as $key=>$list) {
            ?>
            <li><a><?= $list[$key]['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't close `</li>` for this `<li><a>My List</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need a recursive function to build this tree. Here is one that will do what you want. Note that it takes account of the extra (unnecessary?) array layer that you have in your input data, if that doesn't actually exist remove the `[0]` from the reference to `$lists` in the function:

```
function make_list($lists, $parent = 0) {
    $children = array_filter($lists[0], function ($v) use($parent) { return $v['parent'] == $parent; });
    if (!count($children)) return;
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        echo "<li>{$child['name']}</li>\n";
        make_list($lists, $child['id']);
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

make_list($lists);
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hZ07j)

Comment: any ide bro how can i add sub parents into <li>, Example <li>Menu<ul><li>Sub Menu</li></ul></li>

Comment: @NoName that's basically what you are doing already, you can just add them to your data structure and the function should generate the structure for you.

Comment: bro please read this question about parent and answer please. Thank you so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933009/php-tree-change-parent-structure

Comment: @NoName I've posted an answer which is just a minor change to this function

Answer (score 0):

You've still got a bit more to do for the parent/child thing, but to get it working initially, just unwrap the array with the extra `array()` and access the element based without the `$key` like so:

```
$lists = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Menu 1',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'Menu 2',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 2,
        'name' => 'Menu 3',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'Menu 4',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Menu 5',
    )
);
?>
<ul>
<li><a>My List</a>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($lists as $key=>$list) {
            ?>
            <li><a><?= $list['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks, im waiting for people to show me the code for parent.